# GeForce GT 710 - Ubuntu is slow and unresponsive when more than one monitor is connected

Tags: drivers, nvidia

Just bought two new 4k monitors but of reasons unknown Ubuntu 22.04.1 Jammy gets unresponsive and slow when I connect more than one monitor. Tested on windows with 4 monitors and all works perfect.
So where to begin with troubleshooting?
Have slim troubleshooting knowledge but will begin showing output -

```
sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GK208B [GeForce GT 710]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:41 memory:ee000000-eeffffff memory:f0000000-f7ffffff memory:f8000000-f9ffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-graphics
       product: VESA VGA
       physical id: 1
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=640,480
```

```
dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-470:amd64                   470.161.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-470                       470.161.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-470:amd64                470.161.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-470:i386                 470.161.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-470:amd64                 470.161.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-470:i386                  470.161.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-egl-wayland1:amd64               1:1.1.9-1.1                             amd64        Wayland EGL External Platform library -- shared library
ii  libnvidia-encode-470:amd64                 470.161.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-470:i386                  470.161.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-extra-470:amd64                  470.161.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        Extra libraries for the NVIDIA driver
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-470:amd64                   470.161.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-470:i386                    470.161.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-470:amd64                     470.161.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-470:i386                      470.161.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-470:amd64                   470.161.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-470:i386                    470.161.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.15.0-47-generic 5.15.0-47.51                            amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-47
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.15.0-48-generic 5.15.0-48.54                            amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-48
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.15.0-50-generic 5.15.0-50.56+1                          amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-50
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.15.0-52-generic 5.15.0-52.58+1                          amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-52
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.15.0-53-generic 5.15.0-53.59+1                          amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-53
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.15.0-56-generic 5.15.0-56.62+1                          amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-56
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.15.0-57-generic 5.15.0-57.63+1                          amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-57
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.15.0-58-generic 5.15.0-58.64+1                          amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-58
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-470-generic-hwe-22.04 5.15.0-58.64+1                          amd64        Extra drivers for nvidia-470 for the generic-hwe-22.04 flavour
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.15.0-47-generic 5.15.0-47.51                            amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-47 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.15.0-48-generic 5.15.0-48.54                            amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-48 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.15.0-50-generic 5.15.0-50.56+1                          amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-50 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.15.0-52-generic 5.15.0-52.58+1                          amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-52 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.15.0-53-generic 5.15.0-53.59+1                          amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-53 (objects)
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.15.0-56-generic 5.15.0-56.62+1                          amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-56 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.15.0-57-generic 5.15.0-57.63+1                          amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-57 (objects)
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.15.0-58-generic 5.15.0-58.64+1                          amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-58 (objects)
ii  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-56-generic  5.15.0-56.62+1                          amd64        Linux kernel signatures for nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-56-generic
ii  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-58-generic  5.15.0-58.64+1                          amd64        Linux kernel signatures for nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-58-generic
ii  mate-optimus                               21.04.0-1                               all          MATE Desktop applet for controlling NVIDIA Optimus graphics cards
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-470                   470.161.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-driver-470                          470.161.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-470                   470.161.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-470                   470.161.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                               0.8.17.1                                all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                            510.47.03-0ubuntu1                      amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-470                           470.161.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  screen-resolution-extra                    0.18.2                                  all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-470              470.161.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

Edited information and added:

```
ERROR: apport (pid 1948) Sat Jan 21 12:26:51 2023: called for pid 1910, signal 5, core limit 0, dump mode 1
ERROR: apport (pid 1948) Sat Jan 21 12:26:51 2023: executable: /usr/bin/ibus-daemon (command line "/usr/bin/ibus-daemon --daemonize --xim")
ERROR: apport (pid 1948) Sat Jan 21 12:26:52 2023: gdbus call error: Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

ERROR: apport (pid 1948) Sat Jan 21 12:26:52 2023: debug: session gdbus call:
ERROR: apport (pid 1948) Sat Jan 21 12:26:52 2023: wrote report /var/crash/_usr_bin_ibus-daemon.999.crash
ERROR: apport (pid 28200) Sat Jan 21 17:23:39 2023: called for pid 24038, signal 11, core limit 0, dump mode 1
ERROR: apport (pid 28200) Sat Jan 21 17:23:39 2023: executable: /usr/bin/lxqt-config-monitor (command line "/usr/bin/lxqt-config-monitor -l")
ERROR: apport (pid 28200) Sat Jan 21 17:23:40 2023: gdbus call error: Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

ERROR: apport (pid 28200) Sat Jan 21 17:23:40 2023: debug: session gdbus call:
ERROR: apport (pid 28200) Sat Jan 21 17:23:40 2023: wrote report /var/crash/_usr_bin_lxqt-config-monitor.1000.crash
ERROR: apport (pid 28216) Sat Jan 21 17:23:41 2023: called for pid 24046, signal 11, core limit 0, dump mode 1
ERROR: apport (pid 28216) Sat Jan 21 17:23:41 2023: executable: /usr/bin/lxqt-config-monitor (command line "/usr/bin/lxqt-config-monitor -l")
ERROR: apport (pid 28216) Sat Jan 21 17:23:42 2023: gdbus call error: Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
```

Comment: I had a Intel Haswell based system with nVidia GT620. Found the Haswell's internal video was higher spec for most things than the nVidia card. Does that card even support 2 4K displays?

Comment: In Windows 7 running 3 monitors in 4k and one in a less resolution with NO problem. for hours. Still banging my head on the wall trying to figure out what is wrong. Maybe its a setting somewhere, or driver is not good. Have reinstalled the nvidia driver and still problem. Now thinking maybe its a desktop manager issue also.

Comment: Does this correctly ID your new monitors? `sudo get-edid | parse-edid` You may need to install `sudo apt install read-edid`   Also shows other info on monitor.
`

Comment: Brother thank you for reaching out to someone in desperate need of help. I ended up purging the whole complete nvidia package with - sudo apt purge *nvidia*.
Autoremoved any leftovers and rebooted and then using standard Nouveau. This acctually worked fine in multiple monitor setup but I decided to install nvdidia once again, via Software and update, additional drivers and then picking correcy proprietary driver. Rebooted and now works even better than before. Odd indeed. However I will have second thoughts running Ubuntu because I use this on a business critical system.